# How to design DTO about Intersection Entity with attribute

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, orm, dto

I'm wondering How I can design DTO about Intersection Entity (about many-to-many relation) with attribute.

For example, if there was CAR, PARTS, CAR_PARTS table, like

```
CAR (ID, NAME, ...)
PARTS (ID, NAME, ...)
CAR_PARTS (CARID, PARTSID)
```

, and let CAR and PARTS have many-to-many relation, then I think we can design DTO as

```
class Car {
    int id;
    String Name;
    List<Parts> partsList;
}
public class Parts {
    int id;
    String name;
    List<Car> carList;  //if necessary
}
```

It's OK.

The question is, if CAR_PARTS table had any attribute, like

```
CAR (ID, NAME, ...)
PARTS (ID, NAME, ...)
CAR_PARTS (CARID, PARTSID, QUANTITY)
```

, and here QUANTITY indicates the parts quantity in a car, for example if a car has 4 tyres then QUANTITY is 4, in this case how I can design DTO?

In the classes above they expresses the relationship as having the property of each class. So it seems not to be able to express quantity...

Answer (score 1):

Why not make dictionary like `Dictionary<Parts, Qty> partsList;` or Make `List<CAR_PARTS> parts;` and have car_parts class with required attribute

Comment: If I implement `Dictionary<Parts, Qty> partsList`, then it it's impossible to express additional attributem like

Comment: Sorry the comment above.   Thanks for your reply! If I implement `Dictionary<Parts, Qty> partsList`, then it it's impossible to express additional attribute like CAR_PARTS (CARID, PARTSID, QUANTITY, FOO).  And about the idea `List<CAR_PARTS> parts`, I've actually considered. But the problem in it is, the difference between the pattern that has additional and not. I'm developing a data access library and it's required lower compatibility. So it's problem to change the design if in the future there appears additional attribute. So I want to know if there is some other good idea.